# NetShareCheck how it exactly works

Tags: c++, winapi

I have to check that my folder is a network (i.e. shared) folder. For example, you have something like this: `net use G: REMOTE_DRIVE_HERE`. Then you want to know if the given path is the path on your local machine or drive G. I use this but not sure if it's correct:

```
bool IsNetFolder(const std::wstring& path)
{
    if (checkStartWithDirectory(path, L"\\"))
        return true;
    
    const auto size{ path.size() + 1 };
    auto copy{ new wchar_t[size] };
    std::memcpy(copy, path.c_str(), size * sizeof(wchar_t));
    
    DWORD type{};
    auto res{ NetShareCheck(nullptr, copy, &type) };

    delete[] copy;
    // not sure about this
    return res == NERR_DeviceNotShared;
}
```

This code does exactly what I want but it questionable. I think that it works because I use `NetShareCheck` with `nullptr`: Windows look at all nonlocal drives and says that I cannot share it then return `NERR_DeviceNotShared` to me.

As Richard Critten said, it's better to use `GetDriveType`.

Comment: Using nullptr (or NULL) means that the local computer is used (and not some remote server etc,.). If this is what you want there's no problem with it. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmshare/nf-lmshare-netsharecheck.

Comment: [GetDriveType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getdrivetypew) return `DRIVE_REMOTE - The drive is a remote (network) drive.`

Comment: @wohlstad Yeap, I read this docs. But still have question, is my code correct? I thought that NetShareCheck must return Error_Success only if folder shared

Comment: Why are you copying the string and not using path.c_str()

Comment: @DavidHeffernan NetShareCheck needs LMSTR, not LMCSTR (also I cannot use data, because it becomes mutable only in c++17)